# Avoid word going next line in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, constraints, text-alignment, ios-autolayout

How to Show the thunderstorm word in one line and Early for another line...

[image]

Please help me out this...

Comment: use `autoshrink` property with `minimum font scale`

Comment: Yes I used that property also dosen't work

Comment: No I want to show that text in two lines without breaking

Answer (score 0):

You should select Word Wrap in parameters of the label:

[image]

Comment: @YanoRatheez then width of your `UILabel` is not enough to show the word "thunderstorm"

Comment: It has enough width to show that word> I set the width as >=80 in constraint